# Diagonalization of a Matrix in terms of other matrices and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Task: Let A be a symmetric matrix having only one eigenvalue λ and C be a matrix that diagonalizes A by a similarity transformation. Find a simplified expression for A in terms of λ, C, and I, the identity matrix.

I know that the similarity transformation is $C^{-1} A C$ and that eigenvalues can be obtained from $Ax - Iλx = 0$. But I have just no clue how to describe A in terms of λ, C , and I.

I know that that   $Iλx$ is a diagonal matrix (this is the matrix with the eigenvalues)
so I came up with

$C^{-1} A C = Iλ$

I doubt this is even on the right path.

Comment: If you want $A$ in terms of $C$, $I$, and $\lambda$, then multiple on the left by $C$ and the right by $C^{-1}$.

Comment: You are on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{C}$ diagonalizes $\mathbf{A}$ by a similarity transform, we have as you stated
$$
\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{AC} = \lambda\mathbb{I}\tag{1}
$$ 
To get $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of the other matrix and eigenvalue, $\lambda$, multiple equation (1) on the left by $\mathbf{C}$ and right by $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$. Then you will have $\mathbf{A}$ as requested since 
$$
\mathbf{CC}^{-1} = \mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{C} = \mathbb{I}
$$

Comment: Might you have an idea why the question says matrix A is symmetric, or why there is 1 eigenvalue only? Is this just extra information?

Comment: @NondeterministicPolynomialTime what happens when you solve for A

Comment: You should get C * I * λ * inverse(C)

Comment: @NondeterministicPolynomialTime keep going

Comment: Im not really sure if I can simplify more. I know the inverse of C is also the transpose of C because A is symmetric but I don't see how that would simplify more.

Comment: What is CI and can a constant commute with matrices?

Comment: So it would just be λ?

Comment: Not just lambda.

Comment: With Identity matrix too..

Comment: Now I feel dumb xD

Comment: Yes which is symmetric too